# 'receiver' is not defined while it does has value in it

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt

I've been trying to make this one function run and it always came up with this error telling me that 'receiver' is not defined while 'receiver' is actually a user-input word and is passed to this window that im trying to run this function on. What did i do wrong? 
Code simplified for the first window:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from SecondWindow import Ui_SecondWindow

class Ui_FristWindow(object):

     def setupUi(self, FirstWindow):        
        MainWindow.resize(900, 700)

        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()               

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(FirstWindow)        

        self.lineEdit1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)       
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit1)

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)        
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.openwindow)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)

     def openwindow(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.receiver = self.lineEdit1.text()
        self.ui = Ui_SecondWindow(self.receiver)
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()
```

Code simplifed, kept only the important parts for second window

```
import sqlite3
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

conn = sqlite3.connect('storage.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

class Ui_SecondWindow(object):

    def __init__(self, receiver):  #This is where the word got passed on from the first window
        self.receiver = receiver    
        print (self.receiver)      

    def select_db(self): 

        cursor.execute(('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE Dragons = ?', self.receiver)) 
        data = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in data:
            row[0] = data2
        data2 = str(data2)
        print(len(data2))
        self.label_5.setText(str(data2))

window2 = Ui_WordWindow(receiver) # This is where it tells me that receiver is not defined while i already passed the word on receiver in __init__ func 
window2.select_db()
cursor.close()
conn.close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your program up to the point of error:

```
import sqlite3
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

conn = sqlite3.connect('storage.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

class Ui_SecondWindow(object):
    # define a class

window2 = Ui_WordWindow(receiver)
```

Nowhere in this have you defined `receiver`.  The class `__init__` function requires this value before it can execute.  That method's local variable `receiver` does not have a value until you supply it, and the two variables are not the same object.

Comment: i see, so i have to make receiver a function as well? and how do i make the 2 variables the same object? sorry im clueless as im new to python

Comment: You need to work through your educational materials to learn these basic tools; this is not a site for individual tutorials.  Back up and do one step at a time, instead of trying to code the entire program, and running past your current abilities.  [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Comment: Overall, it seems that you haven't yet designed your system: you don't know whether `receiver` is a scalar variable or a function.  I don't know, either, since you haven't defined your intended design, and included a lot of code not pertinent to that question.